# How to use updateOption with arrayFilters in spring-data mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document as shown  below in Mongodb:

Now, I want to go to a document based on specific "`_id`" and for that document,  want to  go to "schedule" list in which  for the few specific dates (not only one date, but more than one), I want to update the status as "BOOKED".I went through this link, 
   [How to apply update using Filtered positional operator with arrayFilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906270/how-to-apply-update-using-filtered-positional-operator-with-arrayfilters)
    but in MongoTemplate class, `updateMulti` method does NOT take the `updateOption` parameter. Can someone please help

Me out. really will be appreciated for any suggestion. Thanks.

Note: I am using spring-data version "2.0.3.RELEASE", MongoDB driver version is v3.6.4.

Below is a document:

```
{
      "_id": "x1",
      "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "Date": "2018-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
          "Date": "2018-07-10T00:30:00.000Z",
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
          "Date": "2018-07-10T08:00:00.000Z",
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        }
      ],
      "_class": "com.scheduler.persistance.model.Calendar"
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

It will soon be available in spring-data-mongodb. See : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/656

Using it will look like :

```
new Update()
.set("grades.$[element]", 100)
.filterArray(Criteria.where("element").gte(100));
```

In the meantime, you should be able to use it with their snapshot maven repository:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.DATAMONGO-2215-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 5):

If there is no "updateOption" in spring-data, then we can use plain driver jar. I hope it will solve your problem.

```
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z');
format.setTimeZone("EST");

List<Date> dateList = Arrays.asList(new Date[]
                                {format.parse("2018-07-10T00:30:00.000Z")}
                               );

db.getCollection("test").updateMany(new Document("_id", "x1"),
        new Documen("$set", new Document("schedule.$[elem].status", "booked")),
        new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(Arrays.asList(new Document[]
            {new Document("elem.Date", new Document("$in", dateList))}
        )));
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, I am more looking into the spring data solution. I appreciate your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// Assuming your collection is based out of class by name Test.class

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is("someID");
Update update = new Update();
update.set("schedule.$[myRec].status", "BOOKED" );
update.filterArray("myRec.Date", dateValue);
FindAndModifyOptions options = new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true);
mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, options, Test.class);
```